# Strange colors in Image viewer and firefox

Tags: display

I've recently stumbled upon incredibly irritating issue with color display in firefox and image viewer. Some colors are just off, like red instead of blue etc.

This problem doesn't exist in Chromium, or most other apps I've been using.

What is the cause and how to fix it?

--Ubuntu 13.04 64x

Comment: This could be a driver issue. What drivers are you using (nvidia/ati/...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command in the terminal

```
xprop -root -remove _ICC_PROFILE
```

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs it removes default color profile which works wrong

Comment: Erm right. I could guess that this removes the default profile, but _why_ does the default profile need removing in the first place?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs ubuntu creates this default profile each time after system boot and it does not work as expected, even if you will set another color profile per default, it's a bug and there are many open issues for this bug. There is no other solution

Comment: Likely [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/938751).

Answer (score 2):

It may be a color profile issue.

Go to **System settings > Color**

You will see your device. Click on your device and click the button <kbd>Add profile</kbd>.

In the menu that comes up select **default color profile** and restart your application.

Answer (score -3):

Try going to Add-ons in firefox and disable them and then reactivate. 
For me it worked.