# Color mismatch in image viewers

Tags: google-chrome, display, colors, image-viewers

[image: example]

Here is same image open in Chrome, feh, and Ubuntu's default image viewer (http://www.flatdesigncolors.com/assets/colors.png).

Can someone explain what is happening here, how can I know which representation is most accurate, and how to make it appear the same in different applications?

Comment: I have this issue too. The problem, as far as I can tell, is in the default image viewer (the eye of gnome), as all other image viewers and programs (Firefox, Mirage, ViewNior, etc.) show images correctly. Anyone found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Actually, I think I've found a workaround. I've done some digging, and as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975291/139735) says, you need to remove a rogue ICC profile. Here's how you do that:

```
xprop -root -remove _ICC_PROFILE
```

## Persisting upon Reboot

There are reports floating around that it resets upon reboot, so if this happens to you, then try adding the command to `~/.profile`. To do that execute this command:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

The text editor will now open. Paste the command at the bottom of the file. I suggest you add a comment (A line preceded by a hash `#`) to remind your future self as to what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You could also delete the colour profile in colour settings.

If the remove button is greyed out, you can simply deny access to the colour profile files:
`$ sudo chmod 000 ~/.local/share/icc`

Answer (score 0):

As I answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1419022/1475894) (and I'm pasting the answer in the following lines), a GUI solution could be going to **Settings -> Color** and **disabling the Laptop Screen option** (maybe **another option might appear to you**, so I recommend try each and see if it solves the problem). Your printer colors profile might be here too, so make sure to **let disabled only the option that solves your problem**.

Warning: I don't know all the consequences of this change, but it's unlikely that something dangerous occurs (like you getting a black screen).