# Wrong colors on Firefox and Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, 20.10, colors

I installed Ubuntu 20.10 recently and only now noticed that colors are off but only in some places. If I take a screenshot and open it, it displays correctly but on Firefox, it doesn't. I applied the correct color profile, it works in most places except the system itself, I restarted the system as well.

Also tried doing what is said here, [Strange colors in Image viewer and firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300399/strange-colors-in-image-viewer-and-firefox), but it only made all programs display wrong colors.

Images:

What shows up:

[image: What shows up]

Correct color:

[image: Correct color]

Firefox (Left) Chrome (Right):

[image: Firefox (Left) Chrome (Right)]

I think that the [color settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgam3.png) is the problem:

[image: Screenshot of color settings]

If so is there any way to make it work full screen?

So today I reinstalled Windows 10, colors were wrong before and after updating everything but I fixed it by disabling the [color temperature control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GPMs.png):

[image: Color temperature control]

Is there a option to do that on Linux?

System:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 2200G
- GPU: AMD RX580
- Display Hanns.G HW173D

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out basically I had the colors wrong before and now with Linux they are accurate because I found this image [image: sky]

And it only looks natural when I turn on color correction on radeon software, with color correction off it looks way too purplish. I was so used to seeing colors like they were On windows that I automatically assumed that the fault was on Linux and not on Windows.

Comment: The image you posted is pretty much indigo tinted / purpleish / unnatural. If you see this image looking natural on any of your devices / OSes, then be aware that it's a trap. Any image you edit on your machine may look all-right to you, but will look weird likely for everybody else.

Comment: Normally one would recommend for such case, that you do a "proper color calibration" of the graphics / driver / monitor using the `argyll` software or something similar, but since it's so challenging and it relies on buying an extra piece of colorimeter hardware, I would say simply pick a few reference images, put them in dropbox or something so that you can open them on various devices, and then just "eyeball" it; try to see whether your monitor matches how it looks on a number of other devices.

Comment: oh ok so It really is like that. I for now am going to stick with windows not because I don't wanna use linux but because I wanted to have a proper setup for linux, I'd like to have a kvm with linux and windows, when the time comes I'll probably buy new monitors because I only have one with only one input